# javascript поиск и replaсe по строке с условием

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Имеется строка которая может быть такого вида

```
100.15.98
```

А может и такого

```
940.56
```

Вроде как должно подходить str.match(reg) с флагом g, но не как не могу понять как его применить.

На выходе нужно что-бы если строка имеет 2 точки то replase('.','') (первое вхождение), а если 1 точка, него не трогать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

непонятно зачем вам /g , просто "посмотрите вперед (?=)" нет ли там второй точки

```js
console.log (fix('100.15.98'), fix('100.15.98.11'), fix('940.56'));
console.log (fixGlobal('100.15.98 940.56 100.15.98.11'));
function fix(num = '') {
  return String(num).replace(/^(\d+)\.(?=\d+\.\d+)/, '$1,');
}

//если искать надо в большом тексте, то /g конечно пригодится

function fixGlobal(num = '') {
return String(num).replace(/(^|\D)(\d+)\.(?=\d+\.\d+)/g, '$1$2,');
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за назойливость, а если нужно оставить только последнюю точку в строке, а все остальные заменить убрать?

Comment: В первом примере уберите проверку  начала строки, поставьте /g

Comment: спасибо большое